# SQL Query modification required

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Below is my query which I need to modify so that it show data , date wise, I have one column in nwsa with date. How  can I modify same query so that I can fetch data with specific date.

```
SELECT CODE_ID,
  NAME_CODE,
  SUM(INR_COL + OUT_COL) AS "TOTAL SUM"
FROM nwsa
WHERE CODE_ID='A12A'
OR CODE_ID   ='A12B'
OR CODE_ID   ='A12C'
OR CODE_ID   ='A12D'
OR CODE_ID   ='A12E'
OR CODE_ID   ='A12EB'
OR CODE_ID   ='A12F'
OR CODE_ID   ='A12G'
OR CODE_ID   ='A12I'
OR CODE_ID   ='A12O'
OR CODE_ID   ='A12U'
GROUP BY CODE_ID,
  NAME_CODE ;
```

Comment: add sample data with expected result. and mention 'date' column name

Comment: I would also change the WHERE condition to something like `where code_id in ('A12A', 'A12B', ... , 'A12U')`. Better, those codes should be in a table, and the condition should be `where code_id in (select code_id from that_table)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the query to be as below:

```
SELECT CODE_ID,
NAME_CODE,
SUM(INR_COL + OUT_COL) AS '[TOTAL SUM]',
(*your date column*)
FROM nwsa
WHERE CODE_ID IN ('A12A', 'A12B', 'A12C', 'A12D', 'A12E', 'A12EB', 'A12F',
'A12G', 'A12I', 'A12O', 'A12U')
GROUP BY CODE_ID, NAME_CODE, (*your date column*);\
```

In case, the 'CODE_ID' is expected to grow over time, you may move that to a different table as suggested above by @mathguy .